# how to make text clickable without <a> and show/hide checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

i am creating admin panel of my project and getting some sort of problem, i just wanna make edit button as you can see click able, when when i click on the down besides chechboxes should appear and when again i click over edit button they should hide. i tried myself by many ways but all gone wrong. please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

```
<tr>
            <td class="fl underline" style="margin-bottom:15px;" colspan="3">User Profile<span style="float:right;font-size:12px;margin-top:3px;word-spacing:6px;"><span id="edit_profile">Edit</span> | <span id="del_profile">Delete</span></span></td>       
</tr>
```

```
            <td class="hl">Complete Name</td>
            <td class="hr"><input class="edit_completeName" type="checkbox" value="" style="display:none;"> <?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']; ?></td>              
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="hl">Address</td>
            <td class="hr"><input class="edit_streetAddr" type="checkbox" value="" style="display:none;"> <?php echo $row['street_address']; ?></td>              
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="hl">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="hr"><input class="edit_city" type="checkbox" value="" style="display:none;"> <?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>              
        </tr>
```

Comment: Your hidden text is still easily read.

Comment: Using IDs more than once is invalid in HTML (`id="edit_completeName"`). Consider using a class instead. This might be one of the reasons why it does not work for you...

Comment: @bazmegakapa -- dear its just a sample codes

Comment: And how can we give you good code if your "example" HTML is flawed? Don't use IDs more than once even in example code, please.

Answer (score 1):

[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will show the checkboxes when they are hidden, and hide them when they are shown, it is perfect for this case.

```
$('#edit_profile').click(function () {
    $('td.hr :checkbox').toggle();
});
```

Here I used `td.hr :checkbox` to get the checkboxes. You could also give them a class, and grab them by that. In your example code you have used IDs, but they can only be used once in a HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Any HTML element can be made clickable by binding the click event handler.

In your case

```
$('#edit_profile').click(function(event){
 //Select your checkboxes using the :checkbox filter
 //Toggle their visibility by using the toggle() function.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want any element to be clickable, assign a `.click()` event handler to it in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet5127.htm

Then you need to define what happens after click.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this if you're using jQuery that is

```
$("span#edit_profile").click(function(){
   //show hide here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery, put your clickable text in a  or some other tag and do something like

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
   //do stuff here
});
```